# isnull Method on python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking through the df DataFrame, you notice that there are missing values. Write a function that takes a specific column in a dataframe and returns the number of missing values in that column. The function must take two arguments : the Dataframe name (df in this case) and a column name as a string.

Hint: you can use the df.isnull() function.

my function

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\athini\Downloads\DataScience_job_statistics.csv')
def missing(df,column_name):
    ##Start Code
    number =column_name.isnull().sum()
    df[number]
missing(df,"gender")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For select column use `[]`:

```
def missing(df,column_name):
    return df[column_name].isnull().sum()
```

Or:

```
def missing(df,column_name):
    return df[column_name].isna().sum()

missing(df,"gender")
```